# when i try to alter table i cannot see my values on MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

When I pressed alter table, I can't edit my variables because it is blank as shown from the picture. I am not able to change anything and see what variables my table has.

The picture shown of MYSQL problem:
[image: MYSQL picture]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which variables you mean, but your actual problem might be that the table editor is too small to show the list of table columns. If you make the Workbench window taller or close the output pane, then you will have more vertical space to show all editor parts like shown here:

[image]